# the root filesystem on /dev/sd1 requires a manual fsck. How does one do this?

Tags: 15.10

I'm trying to repair Ububtu 15.10 crash/lockup boots up with no icons on screen, many repairs did not sove this problem, so created a dvd install for 15.10.
But after all this, It comes back with "the root filesystem on /dev/sd1 requires a manual fsck." How does one do this ? I'm not a software dev/writer etc

Answer (score 5):

The best way is to use a Live CD/DVD to access your system (as you cannot run fsck on a mounted system). Two steps are then required:

1. Boot your computer using a 'Live' CD/DVD
2. Open a Terminal window and run:

   ```
   sudo fsck /dev/sd1
   ```

Confirm first that the drive number: `sd1` is actually the correct one from your error message...

Answer (score 5):

At the prompt, just write:
`fsck -y /dev/sd1`

Comment: the `-y` is important... prevents a bunch of prompts about "i'm about to fix this... is this?"

Answer (score 1):

I am on Ubuntu 16.4. I faced the same issue. Any command I want to autocomplete, it comes with:

```
bash: cannot create temp file for here-document: Read-only file system
```

I was challenged by a black screen with the message

```
....on /dev/sd1 requires a manual fsck
```

I tried with `sudo fsck` at initramfs prompt, no chance. Then I type "help" there to get clue. Then I type `sudo fsck /dev/sda1`. It prompts me with lots of choices (y) for yes. I keep moving till I got the prompt initramfs. There I type exit and I got back my original set up.

Comment: Use the ´-y` option to fsck to avoid the answering yes to each error.